# No puedo conectarme con mi servicio mediante retrofit2 usando el API 19

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

El problema que tengo es que estuve probando con diferentes versiones del `SDK` y con un `samsung SM-A500M` version del API 19 salta de frente al `onFailure` y el error que me sale es el siguiente:

> SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x78cb85f0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

He probado con el API 22 a más y si conectó sin problemas.

La clase que usé es esta

```
class UnsafeOkHttpClient {
companion object {
fun getUnsafeOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient.Builder {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
            @Throws(CertificateException::class)
            override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
            }

            @Throws(CertificateException::class)
            override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
            }

            override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate> {
                return arrayOf()
            }
        })

        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, java.security.SecureRandom())

        val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory

        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
        builder.hostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true }

        return builder
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
}
}
}
```

y la forma en la que la uso es esta

```
val okHttpClient = UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.RUTA_API)
        .client(okHttpClient.build())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

También he intentado usando la librería `'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'`, pero me sale el mismo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El dispositivo que comentas tiene Android 4.4.4 (KitKat), recuerdo este problema en Android 4.4, el cual es relacionado a que al protocolo criptográfico que usas al soportar `SSL`.

Es importante hacer notar lo que indica la documentación para el uso de [SSLContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html):

> Cada implementación de la plataforma Java es requerida para soportar > siguiente protocolo SSLContext estándar: **TLSv1**

[De hecho el que debe ser usado actualmente es `TLS` ya que es el sucesor de `SSL`, pero en el caso de Android es importante la siguiente información](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para la API 19 puedes usar `SSLv3` o `TLSv1` siendo lo recomendable `TLSv1`.**

```
 val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1")
```

Comment: Hola. 
He probado como indicaste, solo poniendo el TLSv1 en mi getInstance, pero no funciona :/  me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: @SebastianPeredoMurga Sebastian, revisa si existe el algoritmo si no usa ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded() para instalarlo, revisa aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468807/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-ssl-handshake-aborted-on-android-old-devices